# In mongo, can you rebuild one single index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

In mongo, you can rebuild all indexes with

```
db.collection.reIndex()
```

But is there a way to rebuild a single index?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Do you consider dropping the index and recreate it with `background: true` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The db.collection.reIndex() drops all indexes on a collection and recreates them. This operation may be expensive for collections that have a large amount of data and/or a large number of indexes.

It's very costly operation and blocks all the operations on the collection for the duration.

> Use dropIndex to remove one Index and createIndex to create it back as rebuildIndex is not supported for only one index

And 5.0 onwards, `reIndex` will be restricted to standalone instances.

Comment: this command removes ALL indexes, i wish to remove and rebuild ONE index out of many.

Comment: Use [dropIndex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) to remove one Index and [createIndex](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) to create it back as rebuildIndex is not supported for only one index

Comment: would you please answer and i'll mark your answer as correct, thanks for your help!

Comment: This is an answer :)

Comment: the actual answer is the comment

Answer (score 0):

Identify all your indexes with:

```js
db.collection.getIndexes();
```

Find the one you want to rebuild, e.g.:

```js
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "fld1" : 1,
            "fld2" : -1
        },
        "name" : "fld1_1_fld2_-1"
    }
```

"Safely" drop and rebuild with explicit specification instead of name:

```js
var idx={fld1:1,fld2:-1};db.collection.dropIndex(idx);db.collection.createIndex(idx);
```